# Loading multiple files and storing its variable name R

Tags: r

I'm loading several dataframes in R, and I would like to know how to store the variable name of the dataframes that I'm loading into a list, so I can work with them later.

```
setwd("/path_to_files")
list.files()
files = list.files(pattern = "toptable*")

for (i in files){load(i)}
rm(files, i)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use your code, you could `load()` into a new environment.

```
myenv <- new.env() # create a new environment
for (i in files){load(i, envir=myenv)}
rm(files, i)

names <- ls(myenv)
```

To use your loaded dataframes, just `attach(myenv)`.

Answer (score 0):

Save some sample data frames:

```
df1 <- df2 <- df3 <- df4 <- mtcars
save(df1, file="toptable1.rda")
save(df2, file="toptable2.rda")
save(df3, file="toptable3.rda")
save(df4, file="toptable4.rda")
```

Get the filenames:

```
files <- list.files(pattern = "toptable*")
```

Load the data from the R data files into the global environment and return the names.

```
sapply(files,  function(x) load(x, .GlobalEnv))
## toptable1.rda toptable2.rda toptable3.rda toptable4.rda 
##        "df1"         "df2"         "df3"         "df4"
```

Pass `USE.NAMES=FALSE` to get rid of the filenames and only keep the loaded object names:

```
sapply(files,  function(x) load(x, .GlobalEnv), USE.NAMES=FALSE)
## [1] "df1" "df2" "df3" "df4"
```

If there are multiple data frames/objects per R data file, you can do:

```
unlist(sapply(files, function(x) load(x, .GlobalEnv), USE.NAMES=FALSE))
```

which will continue to return all the names as a character vector.

You can also keep them together in a `list`:

```
listenv <- new.env()
invisible(lapply(files, function(x) load(x, listenv)))
toptables <- as.list(listenv)
names(toptables)
## [1] "df1" "df2" "df3" "df4" "df5"

class(toptables$df2)
[1] "data.frame"
```